# couchdb installation windows azure ubuntu - can't access on 5984 port

Tags: ubuntu, azure, couchdb, ubuntu-12.04

I just installed the couchdb on my azure ubuntu machine, using the command

```
# sudo apt-get install couchdb -y
```

i can do a curl locally at the same machine

```
# curl http://localhost:5984
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.1"}
```

The endpoint is also configured with 5984 port, but I can't browse to http://:5984

I did netstat -an | grep 5984

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I have installed couchdb in past at my AWS installations quite easy, what could be going wrong here, And do tell me if i should post this to serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it myself, changed the default.ini in /etc/couchdb

changed the `bind_address` parameter from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.